# How to show display alert message using HandleTextChanged event?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created two user input fields which is username and password.

### Here is my Xaml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginUser"
                 x:Class="LoginUser.MainPage">
      <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Entry x:Name="txtUsername"  Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True">
          <Entry.Behaviors>
            <local:ValidationBehavior/>
          </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
        <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065" Clicked="Button_Onclick"></Button>
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

### Here is my ValidationBehaviour.cs file code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UIKit;

namespace LoginUser
{
    public class ValidationBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
    {
        const string pwRegex = @"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$";
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            bool IsValid = false;
            IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex));
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;

        }
        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        }

    }
}
```

I want to show display alert if any the string characters like lower, upper, special characters is removed from textbox.

Comment: how is this any different from your earlier question?  Do you not understand how to use DisplayAlert?  Or are you asking how do you detect if the text has changed?

Comment: For example I'm giving the password like App@1234 in password field so what my question is If I remove the string char like "A" from the Password field then the error should occur.

Comment: TextChangedEventArgs gives you the new value and old value.  You need to compare them and come up with the algorithm that meets your requirements to test for errors.  We can't do that for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login page is not validating in xamarin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075450/login-page-is-not-validating-in-xamarin-form)

Comment: This is the third time that you ask basically the same question.

Comment: This question is different. In the previous question he wanted to solve his problem with behavior. Now he needs to know how he can display a display alert from this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display an alert from anywhere in the `Xamarin.Forms` project via the `MainPage` property of the static `App.Current` e.g.

```
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Test Title", "Test", "OK");
```

If you want to invoke an alert within the `HandleTextChanged` method you must add `async` word first, like this:

```
async void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, emailRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Test Title", "Test", "OK");
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }
```

I do not know if displaying an alert is a good idea, maybe it would be showing a `Label` below `Entry`.

For more information look at this [example in github](https://github.com/nishanil/Xamarin.Forms-Samples/tree/master/Samples%20(1.3)/Samples/Samples).

And [this tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/) that explains how to use Binding with a Behavior